# SyntaxError: Unexpected token M (when running cordova project from Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

When I attempt to run my Cordova app using Visual Studio 2015 using Remote Device, I get an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token M". Visual Studio is installed on windows 10 which is a Parallels VM on my Mac. I have followed the steps to setup remotebuild on my Mac. From Visual Studio - Tools - options, I can successfully connect to the running remotebuild on my mac. The project runs fine when I run it on Ripple in chrome.

Here's a little more background. When I first started working on this project, it was working fine and I was able to run it on the iOS simulator on my Mac. At one point, it started giving me a different error which was related to my iOS developer account. I opened up Xcode on my mac and realized that I needed to login to the developer website and accept the latest license agreement. Once I did that, I attempted to run the project again from Visual Studio. At that point I saw an error related to certificate. I ran the project again, and from then on I keep getting this "SyntaxError: Unexpected token M" error.

I attempted to run an old backup of the same project. The error I get with that is:

```
An error occurred uploading to the build server https://10.0.1.31:3000/cordova: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Here's the part of the output log where I see the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token M":

```
1>  ------    changeList.deletedFilesIos:  (TaskId:11)
1>  ------    changeList.addedPluginsIos: org.apache.cordova.camera@0.3.6,org.apache.cordova.file-transfer@0.5.0,org.apache.cordova.splashscreen@1.0.0,org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.6.0 (TaskId:11)
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPluginsIos:  (TaskId:11)
1>  ------    changeList.addedPlugins: org.apache.cordova.camera@0.3.6,org.apache.cordova.file-transfer@0.5.0,org.apache.cordova.splashscreen@1.0.0,org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.6.0 (TaskId:11)
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPlugins:  (TaskId:11)
1>  ------ Updating plugins (TaskId:11)
1>  SyntaxError: Unexpected token M (TaskId:11)
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:11)
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "MyPyaarApp.jsproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:12)
1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
1>      672 ms  C:\svn\mypyaar\trunk\MyPyaarApp\MyPyaarApp\MyPyaarApp.jsproj   1 calls
1>                672 ms  build                                      1 calls
1>
1>Target Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  CompileTypeScript                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  TrackJsChanges                             1 calls
1>        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                1 calls
1>        0 ms  PreComputeCompileTypeScript                1 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
1>       16 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
1>      266 ms  EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion   1 calls
1>      266 ms  InstallMDA                                 1 calls
1>      391 ms  BuildMDA                                   1 calls
1>
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  MdaVerifySetup                             1 calls
1>        0 ms  MdaTrackJsChanges                          1 calls
1>        0 ms  Message                                    2 calls
1>        0 ms  VsTsc                                      2 calls
1>        0 ms  AssignTargetPath                           1 calls
1>      266 ms  RunMdaInstall                              1 calls
1>      266 ms  CallTarget                                 1 calls
1>      391 ms  MdaVsCli                                   1 calls
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 10):

Found the solution to this!!!

Luckily I had an old backup of my project which didn't produce the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token M" when running it on the remote device. I used a compare tool to see the differences in files/folders. It turned out that the "remote_ios.json" file located in the plugins folder was corrupted. I deleted it and on the next run it generated a proper one and everything now works as expected. I can deploy to the iOS simulator on my mac as well as my iPhone.

I did notice a few more times that the file did get corrupted. So every time I just deleted the file and it got recreated and everything worked. Sounds like a bug in Visual Studio 2015.

Here's how my corrupted remote_os.json file looked like:

```
{
    "prepare_queue": {
        "installed": [],
        "uninstalled": []
    },
    "config_munge": {
        "files": {
            "framework": {
                "parents": {
                    "ImageIO.framework": [
                        {
                            "xml": true,
                            "count": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "CoreLocation.framework": [
                        {
                            "xml": false,
                            "count": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "CoreGraphics.framework": [
                        {
                            "xml": false,
                            "count": 4
                        }
                    ],
                    "AssetsLibrary.framework": [
                        {
                            "xml": false,
                            "count": 3
                        }
                    ],
                    "MobileCoreSe
```

Comment: Also, regarding the error "self signed certificate in certificate chain", all I needed to do was to reset the certificate on remotebuild on the mac by calling:
remotebuild certificates reset

Comment: Woaw i was searching for this one for a while now, thank you sir, you made my day!

Comment: This error still happens with some (not all) Cordova projects and the latest VS2015 Update 1, Cordova Tools 6. For affected projects, deleting the remote_ios.json before every build is a workaround for this problem.

Comment: @NavidHarandi, running the remotebuild certificates reset hasn't fixed the self-signed certificate error for me. Any other ideas on that one?

Comment: Hi Andrew, try this as a temp workaround:
Run remotebuild setting secure mode to false:
(1) run remotebuild --secure false on mac terminal
(2) in VS 2015 “Remote Agent Configuration” settings, set the secure mode to false

Comment: Thanks! I wasted a whole day trying to find what was wrong, and this is it! I still don't understand how a file can be just partially generated like this.

Answer (score 0):

### **The solution is**

*and a more permanent fix for this issue (which worked for me):*

1. Is to delete your plugins folder
2. Restore all of your plugins. *(listed in your `package.json` in an array called `cordovaPlugins`)*

---

*Hint*: Run `cordova plugin ls` to have a list of what you need to add back in.

*I use **Ionic** so I just used this command: `ionic state restore --plugins` and voila problem solved for ever (I hope).*

**PS. FYI don't run cmd as administrator for this, it could be the cause of your issues with iOS apps...**

Got to the root of the problem from [Navid Harandi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231568/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-m-when-running-cordova-project-from-visual-studio/33247146#33247146).