# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" when compiling VS2015 ios cordova app for local device

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

When compiling cordova iOS apps using VS2015 (Tools for Apache Cordova Update 6, 60128.14, release 2/3/2016) for a local device, I'm getting the following error:

```
1>  ------ Platform ios already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  SyntaxError: Unexpected token a
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What's odd is that the project compiles and deploys successfully to the local iPhone exactly once. On the next compile, this error occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231568/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-m-when-running-cordova-project-from-visual-studio

Comment: PS. I posted a solution there that worked for me.

Comment: This is now resolved in VS2015, Update 2 with TACO Update 8

Answer (score 11):

After much experimentation, it appears that VS2015 attempts to use a corrupt remote_ios.json file (in the plugins folder) left over from the previous build. 
The workaround is to delete the plugins\remote_ios.json file before each rebuild for iOS. 
Hopefully, the Microsoft folks take note of this issue and fix in the next update.

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug that was fixed in Update 6 that caused a bad ios.json file to get created when a project was built with no plugins at all. You might still have a bad ios.json file on your Mac that gets re-downloaded after every build.

If you run a clean in VS and then build again, it would force it to do a non-incremental build and therefore not be affected by any old build files. Give that a try and let us know if it solves the problem.

Comment: I actually did a clean a  number of times, but it didn't resolve the issue. I always have to delete the (local) remote_ios.json file. This appeared to start when I did a Debug-build-run on a remote iOS device connected to the Mac. Prior to that, I was not having this problem. So, perhaps doing the remote deploy, then switching back to local broke something.

Comment: We'd love to fix the bug in our next update.  What is in the remote_ios.json file?  The issue we saw before was that it was simply error output from a command.  If we can figure out where the error is coming from, we can prevent it from writing it out to the file in the first place.

Comment: Here are the contents of the remote_ios.json file. This is a test project, let me know if you'd like me to upload somewhere so you can get more info:

`amework.ngcdemo255101"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.ngcdemo255101"
        },
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.ngcdemo255101"
        },
        "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.ionicframework.ngcdemo255101"
        }
    },
    "dependent_plugins": {}
}`

Comment: ok.  So it looks like it might be missing the beginning of the file.  Would you check to see if the file is the same on the Mac?  The default location is ~/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/<buildnumber>/cordovaApp/plugins/ios.json. If the file is whole on the Mac, then it's a download problem.  If not, then it's getting created corrupted.

Comment: I tried to attach the contents of the file, but it was too long for a comment. It is definitely intact on the Mac. Also, I want to emphasize again that this is only happening in this test project. The only thing unique about this project is that it's using the ngCordova plugin from ionic.io. I've since compiled many other Cordova projects on the Mac with no issues. Thanks for your help and for making a great tool in the VS2015 support for Cordova!

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'll have to see if I can find any bugs in our download code.  If it's intact on the Mac then that seems the most likely issue.

Comment: @ToddMoscinski  I am also seeing this "Unexpected token" error in my VS2015 TACO builds.  I hope your team can track this bug down and thanks for providing a great tool - VS2015 TACO!

Comment: Thanks.  I have been able to reproduce the problem on my machine.  We'll work on getting this fixed.

Comment: This will be fixed in Update 8 of the VS Tools for Apache Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue when building for a remote device. For me, it seems to be related to the number of plugins being used.  When I have six plugins, everything works fine.  My plugins/ios.json looks like this:

```
{
 "prepare_queue": {
    "installed": [],
    "uninstalled": []
 },
 "config_munge": {
    "files": {}
 },
 "installed_plugins": {
    "cordova-plugin-device": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.cordova.myappe2785d518e9f4f6ea03055878dd7a400"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-file": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.cordova.myappe2785d518e9f4f6ea03055878dd7a400"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.cordova.myappe2785d518e9f4f6ea03055878dd7a400"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-media": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.cordova.myappe2785d518e9f4f6ea03055878dd7a400"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.cordova.myappe2785d518e9f4f6ea03055878dd7a400"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.cordova.myappe2785d518e9f4f6ea03055878dd7a400"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {
        "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.cordova.myappe2785d518e9f4f6ea03055878dd7a400"
    }
 },
 "dependent_plugins": {}
 }
```

When I add seven plugins (or more) and rebuild, plugins/remote_ios.json gets created and looks like this (with no opening brace):

```
 6ea03055878dd7a400"
     }
 },
 "dependent_plugins": {}
}
```

Removing the seventh plugin and then rebuilding fixes the problem.
I checked the ~/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds//cordovaApp/plugins/i‌​os.json file on the Mac and it is intact and the same as on my local machine.  So something must be getting truncated in the code that creates the remote_ios.json file.