# Visual Studio remotebuild for iOS fails with Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, visual-studio-cordova

I have a Mac mini configured as the remotebuild server. Remote building my cordova app to the Mac was working ok in secure mode for a while but I was suddenly greeted with a **Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain**.

I've followed several suggestions of running the commands,

```
remotebuild certificates reset
remotebuild certificates generate
```

then updating the pin accordingly in Visual Studio to no avail. I *can* build successfully when running in non-secure mode.

```
 remotebuild --secure-mode false
```

I've also tried cleaning my solution in VS2015, nuking the certs folder on the Mac and re-installing remotebuild. It may be worth noting that something in the build process was constantly corrupting the remote_ios.json file so I was having to keep removing that file to build every other time as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231568/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-m-when-running-cordova-project-from-visual-studio).

Any ideas on how to get around this error or why it would suddenly be a point of failure?

Comment: i have same situation like this , my case is i have single mac and have two dev windows machinges , so one dev machine works in secure mode with the mac and another machine will only connect to the remote build while keeping `remotebuild --secure=false`  , whey try to inspect it, that case1: check for the version of the nodejs and cordova case2:are you trying to connect with IP address in visual studio?, My Version for which i made to work with secure mode is nodejs : v0.12.7 cordova:5.3.3

Comment: I tried with both the IP and the computer name, resetting the keys each time and generating a fresh set. Unfortunately I was "on-site" for this issue a few weeks ago and do not have the ability to test it at this point. I am starting to wonder if it wasn't the version of node I was using.

Comment: and adding to my above comment, my window dev machine that run on secure mode and mac has same node version , but d one im using for another dev machine that doesn't use the node that i have been using in my mac

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. It would be great to chat with you about this issue. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Comment: @JordanMatthiesen short answer is no, not at the moment. I was working on site and experienced this problem but I am no longer working on the project so I'm unable to test anyone's proposed solution. I do appreciate you guys being proactive! Great tool you guys are building!

Answer (score 4):

This "self signed certificate in certificate chain" error can happen if remotebuild generates a certificate under one identity (hostname / ip address) and is accessed via another one. The client will look at the certificate and find that it doesn't match what it expected, and so it does not trust the server. My guess is that it began failing for you due to a change in your network architecture.

If you know the identity that other machines will attempt to use, for example if they will use some.buildserver.local, then you can instruct remotebuild to generate a certificate using that identity via `remotebuild --hostname="some.buildserver.local" --secure=true saveconfig && remotebuild certificates reset && remotebuild certificates generate`.

Once you have created new certificates that should match client expectations, if you reconfigure them then they should accept the server's certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Also apart from  those I did restart my client computer as well.